# Dereferencing NULL pointer error while using structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nullreferenceexception

```
struct data_calend {
    int day;
    int year;
    int month;
};

struct personal_data {
    char* first_name, * last_name, * occupation, * department, code[13];
    data_calend birth_date, empl_date;
};
```

So these are my structs and I'm having trouble on a seemingly simple and basic thing:

```
personal_data* p, * min{};
min->empl_date.day = p[0].empl_date.day;
```

Doing this I get an error that says I'm ***Dereferencing NULL pointer 'min'***. It compiles and runs but when it gets there it stops. I tried using the `*` operator in various ways but didn't do anything.

EDIT: Added the initialisation part. Thought I added it before but apparently no.

Comment: Unless you post the part of your code which declares and initializes the `min` variable, few would be able to help you

Comment: What is `min`? How is it defined and initialized? What is `p`? How is it defined and initialized? Please create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: I don’t recommend storing dates as a tuple of Gregorian date components because you can end-up with values like `day == 32, month == 13, year = -1`. Date programming is *hard*. Is there a reason you’re not using `time.h`?

Comment: @Dai I know that if I'm going with this method i can easily get errors like that but it's for a homework for university and I have to do it like this, and also don't know yet how to use `time.h`

Comment: A very important note: The code you show, as you show it, isn't C. It's C++.

Comment: As for your problem, a pointer is what it names implies, something that is pointing somewhere else. A pointer needs to be pointing to a valid "somewhere else" for you to be able to dereference it. A value-initialized pointer (like `min` is) will be a null pointer, and a null pointer is not valid to dereference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as error says : "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'min'". You're supposed to allocate memory for 'min', so that min pointer can point to it AND de-referencing it aka accessing data it points to - can succeed, like this.

```
        struct personal_data *min = malloc(sizeof(struct personal_data));
        min->empl_date.day = p[0].empl_date.day.
```